# Multiple Local Notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

In my app, I have list of friends say: 3 friends, all these three have birthday details. I need to schedule local notification to show their b’days alert. I know and handled a local notification but how will I handle these multiple notification?

I am setting fire date in "for loop”.Is it proper, See the code.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    for (int i = 0; i< [delegate.viewController.contactList count] ; i++) {
        NSString *birthday = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"birthday"];

        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:birthday];

        localNotif.fireDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        NSLog(@"local %@",localNotif.fireDate);
    }

    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    NSString *itemName = @“Friend Name";
    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:itemName,@"msg", nil];

    localNotif.userInfo = userDict;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

What I want,in this method only I have to set notification for all the friend based on their date. can any one tell me where I’m doing wrong and if I’m missing anything please inform me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make three (or more) local notifications and schedule every one of them with  `scheduleLocalNotification:`, what's the problem?
For example this is what I did in my project:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [prototypeNotification copy];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:dates];
    [notifications addObject:localNotification];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    [localNotification release];
}
```

**UPD**

```
// ...this goes earlier:
static NotificationController *sharedNotificationController = nil;

- (id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        prototypeNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        prototypeNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        prototypeNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

        prototypeNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        prototypeNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        prototypeNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        prototypeNotification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"Body", nil);
        prototypeNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Action", nil);

        enabled_ = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thnx buddy!!! but if m having more than 500 friend and have to schedule everyone.Won’t it be performance effective?

Comment: It's nothing but notification (little window to show two strings of text). I don't think performance would suffer.

Comment: What is here prototypeNotification, is it a property??

Comment: In my case it is just instance variable in my class, NotificationController

Comment: hey Олеr, one more thing to ask, how have u handled applicationDidEnterBackground,method.In my case, its scheduling only for the last localNotification.

Comment: I'm not sure if I didn't misunderstood you, but answer is nothing at all. Local notifications is handled by iOS, not your app.

Comment: D'oh, if it's true, I will be in trouble... I' m going to check it.

Comment: I've checked it. Six notifications were scheduled, and all six alarmed at corresponding fire dates.

Comment: Can u please, show me ur code on applicationDidEnterBackground method.

Comment: It's empty. I don't use it. What's the problem?

Comment: My problem is that, whenever app goes in background, its scheduling for the last notification.

Comment: I have difficulties in understanding you. 1) You want to schedule notifications when your app run in background? 2) You only get one last notifiacation, but not others?

Comment: @iCoder477 So have you got the solution for it?