# Is it possible to have two local notification in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I wanted to have two local notification ,both have  different time ,let say my first notification will give alert after 1 minute and the second will give alert after 2 minutes.

I have tried it to create two in appDelegate but only first one is giving me the notification and not the second one .

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It is Possible to set two  LocalNotification in any iOS Application

See below method by which you can set  multiple LocalNotifications

You just Need to pass required parameter to this method.

```
 - (void)setAlarmFor:(NSArray*)datesArray forTime:(NSString*)atTime notificationName:(NSString*)name

 {  

  for(int dayIndex=0;dayIndex <[datesArray count];dayIndex++)
 {
     Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");//
    if (cls != nil) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
        NSString* dateStr=[datesArray objectAtIndex:dayIndex];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
        NSString *tempString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempDate];
        tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempString,atTime];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];

        NSDate *firetAtThisDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempString];

        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[cls alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate =firetAtThisDate;//here set the Date at which mnotification fire;
        NSLog(@"Notification date is:%@",firetAtThisDate);

        localNotif.alertBody =name;
        localNotif.alertAction = @"Your'Alert message";
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

         localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tempString
                                                             forKey:tempString];//by using this we can further cancel the Notification
        localNotif.userInfo = userDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
        [localNotif release];
        [dateFormatter release];
    }
   }


 }
```

And In Appdelegate Class Prepare Action what you want as Notification Fire

```
//This Below Line will goes to the Appdelegate DidFinishLaunching Method

Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (cls) 
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:
                                         UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification) 
    {

      //do what you want
    }
}

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

//End  of Appdelegate DidFinishLaunching Method.


  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    //do what you want

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the multiple local notification in your application.

[Check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011639/multiple-local-notification-in-iphone)

Hope it helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

sure , you use one or more  local notifications in your app. try this code in your project

```
   -(void) setLocalNotification
{

    NSTimeInterval todayTimeIntervel=[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval nextOneMinTimeIntervel;

     nextOneMinTimeIntervel = todayTimeIntervel + 60 ;

    NSTimeInterval nexttwoMinTimeIntervel;

    nexttwoMinTimeIntervel = todayTimeIntervel + 60*3;

    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nextOneMinTimeIntervel];

    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nexttwoMinTimeIntervel];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];

    NSString *strDate1 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];

    NSString *strDate2 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];

    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:strDate1,strDate2, nil];

    NSArray *titleArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First LocalNotification",@"Second LocalNotification", nil];

    for (int i =0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[arr objectAtIndex:i],@"dateStr",[titleArr objectAtIndex:i],@"title", nil];

        [self scheduleLocalNotification:dic];
    }



}


-(void) scheduleLocalNotification:(NSMutableDictionary*) dic
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat dateFromString:[dic objectForKey:@"dateStr"]]);

    localNotif.fireDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dic objectForKey:@"dateStr"]];

    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";



    localNotif.alertBody = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];

        localNotif.userInfo = dic;

        NSLog(@"value of infoDic %@",dic);

        localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // get app instance
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    // create local notif
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (notification) {
        NSDate *oneMinuteFromNow = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
        notification.fireDate = oneMinuteFromNow;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        NSString *notificationMessage = @"First";
        notification.alertBody = notificationMessage;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        // schedule notification
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        // fire notification right away
        [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

        UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
        if (notification1) {
            NSDate *oneMinuteFromNow1 = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:120];
            notification1.fireDate = oneMinuteFromNow1;
            notification1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            NSString *notificationMessage1 = @"Second";
            notification1.alertBody = notificationMessage1;
            notification1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

            // schedule notification
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];
            // fire notification right away
            [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification1];
    }
```

By writing this you ll get one notification after 1min and second one after 2 min. In "`didReceiveLocalNotification`" method you can check the notification type and can show alert msg.

Hope this will help you.